# How to redraw a ListViewItem when something other than the bound item changes?

Tags: wpf

I've got a `ListView` that's bound to a collection of `Item` objects. I don't own the code for `Item`, so I can't add properties to it for my special binding needs.

I need to color rows in the list based on attributes that I know about each bound item, and since I can't modify the `Item` code, I've accomplished this with a Style trigger and custom converter; the converter transforms each item like so:

```xml
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ItemConverter}}" Value="2">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                 <Border Name="Border" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" Background="{StaticResource MyBrush}">
                     <ContentPresenter />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
</DataTrigger>
```

The `ItemConverter` transforms the bound item into a return code, and I do my special style based on that code.

This works fine, except that the code changes when the user does things, and I need to refresh the view. The only way I can find to do this is to refresh the `ItemSource`, and this is very slow.

What I'd really like is to notify the `ListView` to redraw in such a way that only the visible rows are repainted, without touching the underlying collection, which doesn't need to change. This will affect only a handful of rows, rather than ALL of them, and I suspect this will handle my performance issue. But how to do this?

Comment: Are you saying that the ItemConverter uses information to return based on information that is outside the scope of the item in the list? If that is the case, I'd recommend binding to a different list that you compose with new items that aggregate data from both sources.

Comment: That is what I'm saying. I understand what you mean about composition. Let me give that a try. Thanks.